# Extract pattern of usernames from messages

Tags: python, regex, discord.py

I built a Discord py bot that allows users to communicate across servers (i.e. both users don't have to be on the same server). It works for those with simple usernames such as `littlefox#1234` or `little_fox#1234`.

However, when the username is more complex with spaces such as `little fox#1234` it gets stumped. The bot accepts commands such as `!hello`, `!greet`, `!bye` etc. I tried using regex but that doesn't work either:

```
import re
match = re.match(r"!\w( [a-z]*#[0-9]*)", '!hello little fox#1234')
print(match)
other_match = re.match(r"!\w( [a-z]*#[0-9]*)", '!hello little_fox#1234')
print(other_match)
```

However it does not match anything. Both return `None`. What do I do?

Comment: Did you mean `!\w+` at the start? Try `![\w ]*?([a-z]+#[0-9]+)`

Comment: It matches! But how do I extract the username?

Comment: `match.group(1)`.

Comment: When I do that the 'little' in the 'little fox#1234' gets lost

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/OSc4O4/2

Comment: Sounds like you may be able to switch to using [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) from the commands extension, which can do this for you.  Can you share an example command to test with?

Comment: I'm using `@client.event` The command is `!hello little fox#1234`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:!\w+\s+)?([\w\s]*#[0-9]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OSc4O4/3)

**Details**

- `(?:!\w+\s+)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 repetitions of

  - `!` - a `!` char
  - `\w+` - 1+ word chars
  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `([\w\s]*#[0-9]*)` - Group 1: zero or more word or whitespace chars, `#` and 0+ digits.

Note that in case there must be at least 1 letter and digit replace `*` with `+`: `(?:!\w+\s+)?([\w\s]+#[0-9]+)`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/yfJzQ0):

```
import re
rx = r"(?:!\w+\s+)?([\w\s]*#[0-9]*)"
ss = ["!hello little fox#1234", "little fox#1234"]
for s in ss:
    m = re.match(rx, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))  # The username is in Group 1
```

For both inputs, the output is `little fox#1234`.

Comment: When I do that the 'little' in the 'little fox#1234' gets lost

Comment: @Legion So, `little` is part of the username? Ok, just a sec.

Comment: Yes, the username is: `little fox#1234`

Comment: @Legion All fixed.